Error message about libicui18n.so.70 after laptop upgrade to 24.04
I've recently upgraded my laptop to 24.04 and cannot run a software package. It gives me the following error:
error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.70: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

what software is failing to run?  You might need an updated version of that software because the libicui18n version in 24.04 is probably newer than the version that the software was aware of

You need libicu70. The version of libicu in Ubuntu 24 is libicu74.
Just manually download libicu70.deb and install it with dpkg.
I just assume you are using an amd64 machine.
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icu/70.1-2/+build/23145450/+files/libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb


You need to visit the ICU (International Components for Unicode) release page and find the version you need.
Assume you want version 70.

https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-70-rc

Choose your platform.

I'll use Ubuntu(icu4c-70rc-Ubuntu-20.04-x64.tgz) as an example:
wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-70-rc/icu4c-70rc-Ubuntu-20.04-x64.tgz
tar -xvf icu4c-70rc-Ubuntu-20.04-x64.tgz
# Once completed, you'll get the `icu` directory
ls -al ./icu/usr/local/lib # This directory contains many `.so` files, such as:
# icu/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so -> libicui18n.so.70

# Copy these files to the system directory (using 'mv' in Docker may cause issues, so use 'cp -r' and then delete)
cp -r ./icu/usr/local/lib/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
rm -rf ./icu/
rm -rf icu4c-70rc-Ubuntu-20.04-x64.tgz

